# Array global en blanco despues de dos llamadas ajax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Al hacer una variable global y luego de hacer push después de dos consultas por ajax queda en blanco ¿Pueden decirme si falló en algo?

```
var productoT = [];
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic.contrib.ui.tinderCards2', 'ionicLazyLoad'])
 .run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $ionicConfig, $timeout, $ionicPopup){
 }
.controller('productoGctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http','$ionicPopup', '$ionicLoading', controlfproductoG])

function controlfproductoG ($scope, $timeout, $http, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading) {
  var typeT;

  if (localStorage.getItem('idCategoriaSelecionada')) {
    console.log(1)
    typeT = {
      actionType: 'getProductosCategoria',
      iduser: localStorage.getItem('iduser'),
      idcategotia: localStorage.getItem('idCategoriaSelecionada')
    };
  }
  else{
    console.log(0)
    typeT = {
     actionType: 'get',
     iduser: localStorage.getItem('iduser')
    };
   }

  productoUrl(
   $http,
   'ProductosService.php',
   typeT
  )
  .then(function (dato) {
    verP = dato;
    productoInfoUrl(
     $http,
     'ProductosService.php',
     dato
    )
   .then(function (det) {
     console.log(det);
     productoT.push(det);
   })
 });

 console.log(productoT);
}

function productoUrl ($http, url, dato) {
 var promise = new Promise();
 var prod, datoProducto;
 $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: url,
   data: dato,
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
 }).success(function (res) {
    //console.log(res)
    if (res.code == '0') {
      prod = res.productos;
      promise.done(prod);
    }
    else{
     console.log(res)
    }
  });
 return promise;
}

function productoInfoUrl ($http, url, dato) {
  var promise = new Promise();
  var datoProducto;
  dato.forEach(function (dat) {
    $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {
      actionType: 'getInfo',
      idproducto: dat.id,
      tipo: dat.tipo
    },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (res) {
      //console.log(res)
      if (res.code == '0') {
        datoProducto = new ObjProducto(dat.id, dat.tipo, res.producto);
        promise.done(datoProducto);
      }
      else{
       console.log(res)
      }
    });
  })
  return promise;
}

function Promise () {
  this._callbacks = [];
}

Promise.prototype.then = function (callback) {
   if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
     throw new Error('[Promise.then] El argumento "callback" no es una    función ' + typeof callback);
   }
   this._callbacks.push(callback);
}

Promise.prototype.done = function () {
  var callback;
  var args = arguments;
  for (var i = 0; i < this._callbacks.length; i++) {
    callback = this._callbacks[i];
    callback.apply(null, args);
  }
}
```

Muchas gracias por la información.

Acá está como funciona https://jsfiddle.net/albert925/bu383ck8/11/

Comment: Se debe a la asincronicidad. Por favor revisa esta [pregunta y su respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).

Comment: Según los resultados de tu consola no están saliendo del todo en blanco. Has oído alguna vez de las [promesas](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/General-Promise-Resources)? Si la respuesta es afirmativa deberías saber que `success` está obsoleto y en su lugar deberías usar `then` y `catch` en lugar de usar callbacks en el código. No deberías usar variables globales tampoco pues angular es modular y no es necesario utilizarlas. Como dice @Mauricio probablemente estés intentando imprimir en la consola el resultado antes de obtenerlo.

Comment: @devconcept vale, pero ya lo hise con promesas aun nose porque, pero primero se ejecuta al mostrar el array y despues se guarda con push.

Comment: @AlbertArias Podrías editar la pregunta con en arreglo que le hiciste?

Comment: @devconcept listo, lo puse como lo tengo ahora.

Answer (score 1):

Ya en los comentarios te orientan. Es porque estas mostrando por consola los resultados antes de que se hayan resuelto las promesas, que se están procesando de manera asíncrona. Para ilustrarlo, prueba esto:

```
productoUrl(
    $http,
    'ProductosService.php',
    typeT
)
.then(function (dato) {
    console.log('Promesa 1 resuelta');

    verP = dato;
    productoInfoUrl(
        $http,
        'ProductosService.php',
        dato
    )
    .then(function (det) {
        console.log('Promesa 2 resuelta');

        console.log(det);
        productoT.push(det);
    })
});
console.log('Tras las promesas');
```

El resultado que vas a ver por la consola es este:

```
Tras las promesas
Promesa 1 resuelta
Promesa 2 resuelta
```

Como verás, se llega a la última línea antes de terminar de ejecutar las anteriores, que se siguen ejecutando asíncronamente. Podrás usar la variable global, ya cargada con todos los datos, cuando se resuelva la segunda promesa, pero no antes:

```
productoUrl(
    $http,
    'ProductosService.php',
    typeT
)
.then(function (dato) { 
    verP = dato;
    productoInfoUrl(
        $http,
        'ProductosService.php',
        dato
    )
    .then(function (det) {
        console.log(det);
        productoT.push(det);
    })
   .then(function () {
     console.log(productoT);   
   }
});
```

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias.